# Multivariable calculus (Lagrange multipliers)

Tags: calculus

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers find the shortest distance between points on the parabola $y = x
^2$ and on the
line $x − y − 2 = 0.$

what i tried

I know that i have to use the distance formula $\sqrt{(x(a)-x(b))^2+(y(a)-y(b))^2}$ and minimise it in order to find the shortest distance before i can apply the method of Lagrange multipliers, However im unsure which points should i take in order to use the distance formula.Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: One thing that's useful to do in problems like this: Minimize the square of the distance rather than the distance itself. (It's equivalent mathematically, but the algebra is substantially less tedious.)

Comment: Yup i know that, lets say if used this method and i got my minimum point, do i need to go back to square my minimum point?As in all answers i got will the same whether i square of the distance or not?

Comment: Nope. Whatever points you get from minimizing $d^2$ should also minimize $d$.

Comment: Then how about the minimum value?

Comment: If you've got a point which minimizes $d^2$ and therefore $d$, you can just plug it into the latter to get the minimum value. But this is a bit academic unless you actually carry out the calculation.

Comment: My problem here is that because the points are not given, so im unsure of how to get the points in order to use the distance formula. Could anyone help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $(x, y)$ is the point on the parabola and $(z, w)$ is the point on the line, then it looks as if you have to minimize the $4$-variable function $(x-z)^2+(y-w)^2$ subject to the two constraints $y-x^2=0$ and $z-w-2=0$.